# Can't find desired PythonLibs when using two installations of python

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I have two different versions of python2.6.6 installed in the same Linux CentOS (created using different attributes). 
The locations are given below

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.pyenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/libpython2.6.so    (DESIRED ONE)
```

and

```
/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so
```

For compilation using boost-python, I'm trying to find PythonLibs using this piece of code:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( PythonLibs 2.6 REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )
```

If a computer which only one installation, its works fine, because there is no doubt.

But if I try to run under this scenario, the cmake finds the "out scenario" installation and it breaks the compilation furthermore.

Is there something wrong with this FIND_PACKAGE block?

Rgds.

Comment: there is also another issue, your "undesired" one had `/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so` in it. It looks like 64-bit library to me. Seems like you are kind of mixing 32-bit and 64-bit of Python and asking for trouble. If you remove the undesired one from the environment variable list, it should work for you. simply remove it from the machine unless you have any reason not to?

Comment: It is a multiple user computer, and I have no permission to do that. The reason that I'm creating the workspace is to use my libraries instead the installed ones.

Comment: you can bash into your own python location and use it as long as your version is sandboxed from other users' workspaces. I have a windows machine and I have installed 2.5 and 2.7 Python - no problem. Some of my applications use 2.5 underneath when the scripts are called. But that doesn't break my other stuff written under 2.7.

Comment: Ok. And how I could use it? Is there a different way to do?